# Neural Network : extrapolate between two trainings

Tags: neural-network

Is it possible to train a Network with **2 inputs** : one is the **data** and the other is a **constant** that we define.

We train the network with one set of datas and set the second input to **'10'** for example

then once it has converged, we train with another set of data and set the second input to **'20'** this time.

Now what if i input test data with the second parameter set to '15', *will it automatically **extrapolate*** between the two learned states?

If not, how do i do if i want to do what i explained above : extrapolate ***between* two training states**?

thanks a lot

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add another input as a parameter into the neural network, but I am unsure what benefit you are trying to achieve by adding this input.

You would need to train the neural network with this input so that it would estimate the value between the two trained networks.  This would involve training each individual network first and then training a second network that would extrapolate between states.

If you are trying to modularise each trained Neural Network for specific roles or classifications, and these classifications represent some kind of continuous relationship (for example, weather predictions that specialise for no rain, light rain, moderate rain and heavy rain), then perhaps this input could be used in some way to encourage the output of a particular network.

If you would like to adjust the weights of each network so that some Neural Networks have more preference than others, perhaps an Ensemble approach can assist with different weights for each network (static and dynamic options are available).  If you just want to map the differences between the two networks with different weights, perhaps a linear or non-linear function can be applied between the two networks and mapped to detail the changes between the two trained networks.